# multiple email send in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

while email send got the error like this:

> Message = "Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: sorry, You email could not be sent at this time. Please contact the administrator. (#5.7.1)" And Mail send through my company host.

how could be resolve my code:

```
SmtpClient sC = new SmtpClient();
sC.Host = "smtp.rediffmailpro.com";

sC.Timeout = 20000;
////sC.Port = 25;
sC.Port = 587;

//sC.EnableSsl = false;

sC.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("ex@mail.com","******");

sC.Send(mM);
```

webconfig File:

```
<mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
        <network host="smtp.rediffmailpro.com" port="587" defaultCredentials="true" />
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try port 465

Comment: I tried this port 465.when use this,i got the error "operation has timed out"

Comment: Then i add  sC.Timeout = 20000;